# How to create state of two buttons (Male and female) change on click

Tags: android

I have to make two buttons Male and female and on clicking on any of the button the clicked button gets blue in colour and the other one remains the same and only one button can be enable at one time. How to handle the state of these buttons? This is something like a gender form

I am working in android and i am not getting the logic of how to handle these buttons. Buttons should be two, rectangular and containing Male and female.

The buttons should look the same but only on clicking colour should be changed

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Layout:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/male"
        android:button="null"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/male"
        android:button="null"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="female" />
</RadioGroup>
```

And create my_selector.xml in drawables folder:

```
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#0f0" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And change colors as you like.

Comment: i have tried radio buttons. i just want rectangular shaped simple buttons that change their colour when clicked and act boolean. this solution shows a radio button inside that rectangular button that changes on click @Farid Forootan